# How to wait until thread process finishes in C# using (Delegate Method)

Tags: c#, callback, wait

Kindly help me. My idea is to  continually print Numeric values form 0 to 1000 using thread concept. In case unexceptionally my application closes, how can I write the code WAITING for currently running thread tasks to complete.

Here by i mention sample code...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging;
using System.IO;

namespace Test_AsyncFactorCaller
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public bool Work()
        {
            int nSleep = 100;
            WriteMessage(string.Format("Going to Thread Sleep State for {0} sec", nSleep));
            for (int i = 0; i < nSleep; i++)
            {
                WriteMessage(string.Format("Sleeping = {0}", i));
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
            WriteMessage("Going to Thread Wakeup State");
            return true;
        }
        public void Work_Done(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            WriteMessage("Work_Done");
            AsyncFactorCaller t = (AsyncFactorCaller)((AsyncResult)result).AsyncDelegate;
            bool bResult = t.EndInvoke(result);
            WriteMessage(string.Format("Result {0}",bResult));
            result.AsyncWaitHandle.Close();
        }
        public void WriteMessage(string sMessage)
        {
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\ThreadLog.txt", true))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(sMessage);
                    sw.Close();
                }
        }
        private void btn_asyncCaller_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                AsyncFactorCaller dGate_caller = new AsyncFactorCaller(Work);
                AsyncCallback Completed_callBack = new AsyncCallback(Work_Done);
                AsyncOperation asyncOperation = AsyncOperationManager.CreateOperation(null);
               IAsyncResult result = dGate_caller.BeginInvoke(Completed_callBack, "Test thread");
             }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
            }
        }
       public delegate bool AsyncFactorCaller();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using the Task Parallelism Library? See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609(v=vs.110).aspx. It makes light work of multithreading.

Comment: What's the use of triggering an asynchronous operation and then waiting for it to finish? This makes no sense at all!

Comment: you should use async-await
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx

Comment: Thomas Weller : i triggering the asynchronous operation. During the processing time if i kill the application(.exe) asynchronous operation also stop without finishing it's current process. But i want if i kill the station (or) Application (.exe) asynchronous operation waiting for finish it's current thread Process.

(Sorry for my bad english...)

Comment: Thomas Weller : why i triggering an asynchronous operation and then waiting for it to finish means just imagin the work function do very big process so it's take more execution time (Thread Sleep Time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are really sure that this is what you need to do, try using a [WaitHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.threading.autoresetevent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
AutoResetEvent _blocker = new AutoResetEvent(false);

//In background thread
_blocker.Set();

//Where you want to wait for it
_blocker.WaitOne();
```